# Error -- jQuery('span.timeago').timeago(); is not a function

Tags: javascript, wordpress, function, lightbox, buddypress

I installed lightbox on my website. When I did, my "activity" page stopped working on my Wordpress-Buddypress website.

I used the "firebug" app on Firefox to try and pinpoint the problem.

I got three errors.

jQuery.timeago is undefined

and....

jQuery("span.timeago").timeago is not a function

and...

$("ul.sf-menu").superfish is not a function

It seems like the lightbox is causing these things to stop working? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try viewing your page source and following the links to your scripts. Either a), the scripts are incorrectly included, or b), you're including jQuery 2 times, and overwriting the bindings you previously bound to. Extended, that is.

Basically what the errors mean is that jQuery was not properly told how to implement those functions.

Comment: for the first error up above in the source code, i have `<script type="text/javascript">
var rsBpActivityRefreshRate = 10;
var rsBpActivityRefreshTimeago = true;
jQuery.timeago.settings.refreshMillis = 0;
</script> ` then for the second error I have `if (typeof rsBpActivityRefreshRate == "undefined")
{
rsBpActivityRefreshRate = 10;
}
if (rsBpActivityRefreshTimeago)
{
$('span.timeago').timeago();
} ` and for the third error, I have `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul.sf-menu").superfish();
});
</script> `

Comment: so thats what i have in the source code. how would I check to see if the jQuery was included 2 times?

Comment: @user1164029: That's not what I mean. You will have some tags somewhere that include the actual function definitions. Something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.com/file.js"></script>`. You need to verify these are correctly linked, which you can do by pasting the URL into your browser, or clicking the links when you're viewing the page source, and then, you need to verify their load order is correct. Including the function definitions before jQuery is loaded will not help you at all.

Comment: okay thanks for explaining. When I added lightbox to my website, I used a plugin on Wordpress to add the scripts to my header. I checked the links and they are all linked up correctly. so are you saying that the jQuery is supposed to be loaded before the javascript files? and if you want to look at my source code it is at www.pokemonsocial.com/social

Comment: @user1164029: If you're not, install Firefox + Firebug addon, or use Google Chrome. Next, right click on your page and inspect. You'll see right away 4 errors. The first of which is a syntax error on line 118. You need to go fix all of those.

Comment: okay i found that using the firebug addon. i see where they syntax error is on line 118. i can't seem to find which file i need to edit to fix that error

Comment: i changed the area of where I added the code for my lightbox (I moved it higher up so that it is before all the wordpress and buddypress javascript links.) now I am getting only two errors instead of four

Comment: and when i moved the lightbox javascript codes above all the other javascript codes, now my comments will work but my lightbox will not work. does this mean that I am loading something twice?